# (LigHTTPd) RegExp Rewrite Rules

Tags: regex, lighttpd

I'm writing some of my own rules for a few PHP scripts I'm writing, even though I have little experience with regexp. Note: little.

Basically I want to pass all URLs except a few as arguments to index.php, rewriting most URLs defined as slugs in a database.

ie: /admin, /config, /images, /lib and /template exists, but I do not want to be rewritten.
But everything else, I want passed as arguments to index.php.

I'm doing this currently with:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
    "^/(.*)$" => "/index.php?$1"
)
```

Which works beautifully with the database slugs, however it also redirects the folders listed above. These contain files needed to be directly accessed, but I can't find anywhere describing how to exclude strings from a match.

Once I know how to do this, I can figure out the rest, but being new to regexp I don't know where to start.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**
I've since given these a shot:

```
"^/(index\.php|admin|config|images|lib|template)" => "$0",
```

For which FF reports an endless redirect for those folders;

```
"^/(?!(admin|config|images|lib|template))(.*)$" => "$0"
```

Doesn't match everything but the folders;

```
"^/([^(admin|config|images|lib|template)]*)$" => "/index.php?$1"
```

Again, doesn't rewrite anything;

```
"^/(.*)$" => "/index.php?$1"
```

Rewrites everything, including the folders which I don't want rewritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have achieved what I was looking for with the following expression:

```
"^/(?!(index\.php|admin|config|images|lib|template)).*$" => "/index.php?$0"
```

I then just

```
trim( $_SERVER['argv'] ,"/")
```

in index.php to get the slug.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
    "^/(index\.php|admin|config|images|lib|template)" => "$0",
    "^/(.*)$" => "/index.php?$1"
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, FF gives me an endless redirection error, which is also what I got when I tried a simple:
    "/template" => "/template"